# sql query - true => true, false => true or false

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, boolean-logic, bit

Simple query, possibly impossible but I know there are some clever people out there :)

Given a boolean parameter, I wish to define my where clause to either limit a certain column's output - or do nothing.

So, given parameter @bit = 1 this would be the result:

where column = 1

given parameter @bit = 0 this would be the result:

where column = 1 or 0

i.e. have no effect/show all results (column is a bit field)

I'm not wanting dynamic sql - I can settle for fixing this in code but I just wondered if there's some clever magic that would make the above neat and simple.

Is there? I'm using sql server.

cheers :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer `column = 1 or @bit = 0` works if column may only be 0 or 1.  If column may be any value you want:  `column = 1 or @bit = 0 and column = 0`.

Comment: I missed that you said column was a bit field!

Comment: be sure to add parentheses when mixing AND and OR

Comment: This is a particularly common pattern for report queries, where maybe you have a filter for some category, but also want an option to filter by 'All Categories'

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   column = 1 OR @bit = 0
```

If you have an index on `column1`, this one will be more efficient:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   column = 1 AND @bit = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   @bit = 0
```

See this article in my blog for performance comparison of a single `WHERE` condition vs. `UNION ALL`:

- [**IN with a comma separated list: SQL Server**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/23/in-with-a-comma-separated-list-sql-server/)

Comment: Assuming `column` can only be 0 or 1 this is accurate -- but certainly using a `UNION ALL` is less efficient.  The first reduces in the optimizer to either `WHERE column = 1` or no where clause at all (when @bit = 0).  The `UNION ALL` might not be caught by the optimizer (and if it does, it cannot be worse than the first).

Comment: @Adam Luter: UNION ALL is more efficient in SQL Server, since either of the queries will be optimized away. The first query will always use FULL SCAN, even if @bit = 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
where column BETWEEN @bit AND 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   MyTable
where (@bit = 0 OR MyColumn = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ...
from [table]
where @bit = 0 or (column = @bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had come up with a different answer and felt dumb when seeing the consensus answer.
So, just for yucks, compared the two using my own database.  I don't really know if they are really comparable, but my execution plans give a slight advantage to my goofy answer:

select *
from MyTable
where column <> case @bit when 1 then 0 else -1 end

I realize indices, table size, etc. can affect this.
Also, realized you probably can't compare a bit to a -1...
Just thought I'd share.

Comment: yes you can. it's implicitly converted to whatever column is. Also assigning any non zero value to bit gives 1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select ...
 from table
 where column = case when @bit = 0 then 0 else column end
```

this works no matter what the datatype of column is (could even be a string, for example).  If it were, of course, it would be a different default value (not 0)

Answer (score 0):

WHERE column >= @bit

However, this only works for > 0 values in a numeric column. @bit will be implicitly cast to int, smallint etc because of data type precedence.